# Using value from text box in UPDATE command SQL

Tags: vba, ms-access

I made an input form in MS Access and I'm trying to write an `UPDATE` command that sets a certain value to the value of a text box, and also gets a criteria value from a different text box:

```
SQLtext = "UPDATE tblInfo SET name='" & txtValue.Value & "' WHERE ID='" txtID.Value & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLtext
```

but this error occurs:

> "Expected: end of statement"

Please help!

Comment: You seem to be missing an ampersand, `&` just before the *txtID* in `WHERE`. However, the VBA compiler should have warned you as soon as you stepped off the line. Also, compiler would have put spaces in you concatenation. Please check you statement posted here is exactly as you have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing an &, try this:

```
SQLtext = "UPDATE tblInfo SET name='" & txtValue.Value & "' WHERE ID='" & txtID.Value & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLtext
```

The queries are case-insensitive but it is good practice to keep the SQL commands in all uppercase.

If you get any other errors comment them below please.

Comment: tanx guys. no I just miss that here.

Comment: I solve the problem by copying a command in my code but I couldn't find out the reason of error finally. but tanx for your answers